# React defining functions at file scope in functional component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I often find myself wanting to do this kind of thing:

```
import React from 'react'

const helperFunction = () => "Hello world"

const MyComponent = () => {

    render () {
        return (
            <h3> {helperFunction()} </h3>
        )
    }
}

export default MyComponent
```

When webpack bundles all of the files will this function definition be available to other files?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this function definition be available to other files?

No, this function will be accessible only from this file, because you are not exporting it. It will be available only when you export that function either by default or named export.

Like this:

```
export helperFunction

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like browserify then you can just export your function and use it everywhere you import it.

I generally make a file for my utility functions in my react project. It looks like

```
export let foo=()=>{...}
```

And then in my files I just do

```
import foo from ‘.utility.js’
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will this function definition be available to other files?

It will be **not** available for other files. Webpack makes it available only if you `export` it.

If you want to use the same function in several files, you need to create a new file `utils.js` or `helpers.js` and put this function into it:

```
export const helperFunction = () => "Hello world"
```

Then, if you want to use this function in some file, just import it:

```
import {helperFunction} from 'utils';
```